# Strange clipping on blender donut

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to learn blender and started with the blender guru's donut course. I've made it to part 4 level 1 and after modeling the icing, my donut always ends up with one two areas clipping. I've started over several times and followed the instructions exactly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.[image]

Comment: Hard to tell. Maybe something went wrong when you copied to vertices to create the icing. How it looks like when you disable the Solidify modifier? (monitor icon on the modifier) and how it looks in edit mode? Or upload the file so someone can have a look.

Comment: Upload your blend file so we can take a look at the file
here's the link https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sxGjWsrn" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sxGjWsrn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You probably wanted to make a drop shape for the icing. The [Snapping feature](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html) is activated, and this pulled some vertices to a random spot somewhere. Now you have three faces on the bottom of your icing that go from one side to the other.

*Snapping* is the **magnet** icon. When it's activated the vertices snap to the mesh that is near. Sometimes it can happen that it attaches itself to a random spot of the donut somewhere. That's because "near" is, for example, x-z wise in the front view but not y-wise (to the back). So it's pulled back along the y-axis while x and z positions are only adjusted slightly.

[image]

**It's easy to fix:**

- turn off the *Snapping* feature
- select the icing object in *Object* mode and isolate it by pressing <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> (or menu: *View > Local View > Toggle Local View*). Then you will see only the icing. Inspect the bottom.
- go the *Edit* mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). (Most of your icing mesh is hidden, reveal it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (or menu: *Mesh > Show/Hide > Reveal Hidden*))
- select the renegade vertices and move them into place.
- switch to *Object* mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and leave *Local view* (<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>) to see the result

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you! I'm very new to this and there's so much to learn.